Python data filtering to remove outliers around a density plot
Referring to the below plot, I would like to remove all the outliers outside the density region marked in black color oval shape. I can use simple horizontal filters, like, -4 < data < 4. But outliers still remain. I am looking for any technique that precisely captures the density samples but drops the outliers.

Sample data:
x = array([1243. , 1261. ,  973. ,  842. ,  592. ,  499. , 1088. ,  739.5,
        567.5,  536.5,  854. ,  763. ,  671. ,  574. ,  498.5,  510.5,
        541.5,  544. ,  565.5,  482. ,  416. ,  412.5,  440. ,  540. ,
        652. ,  735. ,  878. , 1030. , 1022. , 1105. , 1034. , 1064. ,
       1089. , 1115. , 1145. , 1146. , 1111. , 1117. , 1140. , 1168. ,
        845. , 1173. ,  898. , 1091. ,  591. ,  570.5,  506. ,  592.5,
        682.5,  619.5,  663. ,  593. ,  470. ,  810. ,  694.5,  900. ,
        965. ,  954. ,  771. ,  608.5,  631. ,  593. ,  652. ,  428. ,
        486. ,  445. ,  395.5,  387.5,  383. ,  390. ,  408. ,  420. ,
        470. ,  543.5,  686. ,  550. ,  588. ,  556.5,  475.5,  606. ,
        617. ,  674. ,  571. ,  810. ,  913. ,  868. ,  621.5,  417. ,
        388. ,  428. ,  501. ,  586.5,  668. ,  739. ,  914. ,  829. ,
        966. ,  995. , 1008. ,  961. ])

y = array([[-10.6,   0.4,   0.1,  -0.1,  -0.5,   0. ],
       [-12.5,   1.5,   1.4,   0.9,   0.7,   0.7],
       [  4.5,   0.3,   0.2,   0. ,   0.6,   0.2],
       [  4.6,  -0.7,  -0.8,  -0.9,  -0.7,  -0.8],
       [  1.8,  -1.3,  -1.6,  -1.8,  -1.4,  -1.5],
       [ 10.4,  -1.4,  -1.5,  -1.1,  -1.2,  -1.1],
       [  1. ,  -0.6,  -0.5,  -0.3,  -0.2,  -0.2],
       [  0. ,   0.2,  -0.1,   0.1,  -0.1,  -0.1],
       [ -1.7,  -1.1,  -1. ,  -0.9,  -0.8,  -0.7],
       [  1.6,  -1. ,  -1.3,  -0.7,  -1. ,  -0.8],
       [  0.5,   0. ,   0. ,   0.3,   0.1,   0.3],
       [ -0.1,  -0.3,  -0.5,  -0.2,  -0.1,  -0.1],
       [  0.8,  -0.4,  -0.3,  -0.4,  -0.5,  -0.5],
       [ -1.3,  -0.8,  -1. ,  -1. ,  -1.3,  -1.1],
       [ -0.1,  -1.9,  -2.2,  -1.6,  -1.7,  -1.5],
       [ -0.9,  -1.3,  -1.5,  -1.9,  -1.7,  -2.1],
       [ -0.5,  -0.8,  -0.9,  -1.3,  -1.4,  -1.3],
       [ -0.2,  -0.6,  -0.5,  -0.8,  -1.6,  -0.9],
       [ -0.8,  -1.2,  -1. ,  -0.6,  -0.8,  -0.9],
       [ -1.2,  -0.6,  -1. ,  -0.4,  -1.3,  -0.4],
       [ -1.1,  -1. ,  -1.1,  -1.2,  -1. ,  -1.3],
       [ -0.8,  -0.9,  -1. ,  -1. ,  -2.7,  -1. ],
       [ -1.2,  -1.4,  -1.4,  -1.1,  -1.6,  -1.1],
       [ -0.4,  -0.6,  -0.7,  -0.5,   3.5,  -0.6],
       [  0.4,   0.1,   0. ,   0.1,   7.3,   0.1],
       [  0.2,  -0.1,   0. ,   0.5,   3.2,   0.6],
       [  0.3,   0.4,   0.2,   0.1, -16.7,   0.1],
       [  1.3,   1.1,   1.1,   1.4,  -2.1,   1.3],
       [  1.2,   1.4,   1.3,   1.3,  -1.7,   1.4],
       [  1.6,   1.2,   1.3,   1.5,   1.6,   1.6],
       [  0.8,   1.3,   1.3,   1.1,   1.1,   1.2],
       [  0.4,   1. ,   1.1,   0.6,   0.8,   0.7],
       [  1. ,   1.1,   1.3,   0.9,   1. ,   1.1],
       [  0. ,   0.3,   0.3,  -0.2,  -0.4,  -0.2],
       [  0.4,   0.6,   0.7,   0.1,  -0.1,   0.2],
       [  1.6,   1. ,   0.9,   0.6,   0.8,   0.6],
       [  0.3,   0.6,   0.6,   0.3,   0.4,   0.5],
       [  0.2,  -0.6,   0. ,   0.2,   0.1,   0.2],
       [ -0.3,   0.6,   0.2,  -0.1,  -0.2,  -0.2],
       [  0.4,   0.5,   0.6,   0.2,   0.2,   0.3],
       [ -0.1,   0.1,   0.1,  -0.2,   0. ,  -0.2],
       [ -0.3,  -0.6,  -0.5,  -0.3,  -0.4,  -0.2],
       [  0.2,   0.1,   0.3,   0.1,   0.1,   0. ],
       [ -0.3,  -0.5,  -0.5,  -0.7,  -0.7,  -0.6],
       [ -1.1,  -0.8,  -0.9,  -0.8,  -1. ,  -0.9],
       [ -2.9,  -1.9,  -2.2,  -2.3,  -2.3,  -2.4],
       [ -3. ,  -2.4,  -2.5,  -2.2,  -1.9,  -2.3],
       [ -0.4,  -1.5,  -1.4,  -0.8,  -0.6,  -0.9],
       [  0.4,   0.1,   0. ,   0.4,   0. ,   0.4],
       [ -0.1,  -0.8,  -0.7,   0. ,  -0.1,  -0.1],
       [ -0.3,  -0.6,  -0.3,  -0.2,  -0.2,  -0.2],
       [  0.4,   0.4,   0.2,  -0.1,  -0.1,  -0.1],
       [ -1.9,  -1.6,  -1.8,  -1.7,  -1.8,  -1.8],
       [ -0.5,  -0.8,  -0.8,  -0.6,  -0.1,  -0.6],
       [  0.8,   0.4,   0.5,   0.8,   0.7,   0.7],
       [  1.1,   1. ,   1. ,   0.7,   0.9,   0.8],
       [  0.7,   0.8,   0.9,   0.7,   0.6,   0.7],
       [  1. ,   1.1,   1. ,   0.8,   0.8,   0.8],
       [  0.2,   0.5,   0.4,   0.3,   0.1,   0.3],
       [ -0.3,  -1.2,  -1. ,  -0.7,  -0.5,  -0.8],
       [ -0.4,  -0.5,  -0.4,  -0.2,  -0.4,  -0.2],
       [  0. ,  -0.5,  -0.2,   0.3,   0.1,   0.2],
       [  0.2,   0. ,   0.1,   0.1,  -0.1,   0. ],
       [ -1.1,  -0.6,  -0.8,  -0.7,  -0.6,  -0.7],
       [ -0.8,  -0.9,  -0.9,  -0.6,  -0.7,  -0.6],
       [ -0.7,  -0.4,  -0.6,  -0.5,  -0.6,  -0.4],
       [ -1.6,  -1.2,  -1.4,  -1.1,  -1.2,  -1.3],
       [ -0.5,  -1.6,  -1.5,  -0.7,  -0.7,  -0.7],
       [ -1. ,  -1.2,  -1.3,  -0.6,  -0.9,  -0.8],
       [ -0.7,  -0.4,  -0.4,  -0.5,  -0.7,  -0.5],
       [ -0.1,  -0.2,  -0.3,   0. ,  -0.2,  -0.1],
       [ -0.5,  -0.4,  -0.4,  -0.3,  -0.3,  -0.2],
       [ -0.5,  -0.3,  -0.5,  -0.3,  -0.4,  -0.4],
       [  0.2,   0. ,   0. ,   0.1,   0. ,   0.1],
       [  0.9,   0.7,   0.8,   0.5,   0.6,   0.6],
       [  0.5,   0.6,   0.5,   0.6,   0.5,   0.5],
       [ -0.1,   0.2,   0.2,   0.4,   0.4,   0.4],
       [  0. ,   0.2,   0.1,   0.2,   0.2,   0.2],
       [ -0.4,  -0.2,  -0.4,  -0.2,  -0.3,  -0.2],
       [ -0.1,  -0.1,  -0.1,  -0.3,  -0.2,  -0.2],
       [  0.1,   0.4,   0.3,   0.1,   0.1,   0.1],
       [  0. ,   0. ,  -0.1,   0.2,   0.2,   0.3],
       [  0.7,   0.8,   0.9,   0.6,   0.6,   0.5],
       [  0.4,   0.2,   0.4,  -0.1,   0. ,   0.1],
       [  1.7,   1.4,   1.4,   1.2,   1.3,   1.2],
       [  0.9,   1. ,   1. ,   0.8,   1. ,   0.8],
       [  0.3,   0.5,   0.6,   0.4,   0.3,   0.3],
       [ -1.4,  -1. ,  -1.2,  -0.9,  -0.7,  -0.8],
       [ -1. ,  -1. ,  -1. ,  -1. ,  -1.2,  -1.1],
       [ -0.6,  -0.7,  -0.8,  -0.9,  -0.9,  -0.8],
       [ -0.5,  -0.8,  -0.7,  -0.3,  -0.4,  -0.4],
       [  0. ,  -0.2,  -0.1,  -0.3,  -0.5,  -0.3],
       [ -0.3,   0.2,   0. ,   0.1,   0. ,   0. ],
       [  0.8,   0.3,   0.4,   0.4,   0.5,   0.5],
       [  1.2,   1. ,   1.2,   0.8,   0.8,   0.6],
       [  1.7,   1.3,   1.4,   1.8,   1.8,   1.7],
       [  1.2,   1.1,   1.2,   1.1,   1.3,   1.3],
       [  1.5,   1.6,   1.6,   1.4,   1.7,   1.4],
       [  1.7,   1.8,   2. ,   1.5,   1.8,   1.5],
       [  0.6,   0.8,   1. ,   0.8,   1.3,   1. ]])


@ParmanM.Alizadeh sample data provided.

The code below uses an IsolationForest to separate outliers from inliers. The main parameter to tune is contamination=.
It works on the sample data, but in order to generalise to the larger dataset you have we'd need a more representative sample.

import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

#x, y from OP

x_flat = np.repeat(x, y.shape[1])
y_flat = y.ravel()
xy = np.column_stack([x_flat, y_flat])

#Outlier modelling
from sklearn.ensemble import IsolationForest

contamination_fraction = 5 / 100 #5%
model = IsolationForest(contamination=contamination_fraction * 0.5)
pred = model.fit_predict(xy)

cmap = 'PiYG'
plt.scatter(xy[:, 0], xy[:, 1], c=pred, edgecolor='none', cmap=cmap)
plt.scatter(xy[:, 0], xy[:, 1], marker='.', s=5, color='white')
plt.gcf().set_size_inches(7, 4)
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.gca().spines[:].set_visible(False)

#Legend
plt.scatter([], [], color=plt.get_cmap(cmap, 2)(0.), label='outlier')
plt.scatter([], [], color=plt.get_cmap(cmap, 2)(1.), label='inlier')
plt.scatter([], [], edgecolor='gray', color='white', label='data')
plt.legend()


This seems to be doing a pretty good job. But, how do I apply same to a time-series data?

I think that's worth asking as a new question, probably more suitable for DataScience, where you could lay out the details of the task. Perhaps you could apply the .predict to each time step after you've fitted it on the train series y values.
